# Alternative for html layout with only part of the page scrolling

Tags: html, css

Similar to [html layout with only part of the page scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30295872/html-layout-with-only-part-of-the-page-scrolling) But I'm looking for a fluid layout.

The problem with the current related question is, it was using float which resulting in a fixed view on the mobile view. I've tried using bootstrap span but I'm not sure if it was the alternative to the current snippet:

```html
<div style="width:1250px;">
<div style="float:left; width:1000px">
    <div style="height:120px; border:1px solid #ff00ff;">Testing Content</div>
    <div style="height:200px; border:1px solid #fff000;">Sample Body</div>
    
</div>
<div style="float:right; width:100px; height:320px; overflow:auto;">
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
    <p>items</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-12">
    <div style="height:100px; border:1px solid #ff00ff;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Testing Content1</div>
    <div style="height:120px; border:1px solid #ff00ff;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Testing Content2</div>
    <div style="height:200px; border:1px solid #fff000;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Sample Body</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-7 col-12">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ff00ff;  height: 420px;
  overflow: auto;">
      <div>
        <span>Scrollable</span>
      </div>
      <div style="height:1000px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to implement bootstrap span or other alternative for fluid layout with only part of the page scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

So you should use height:100vh for displaying full height of browser

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-12">
    <div style="height:100px; border:1px solid #ff00ff;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Testing Content1</div>
    <div style="height:120px; border:1px solid #ff00ff;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Testing Content2</div>
    <div style="height:200px; border:1px solid #fff000;" class="col-xs-12 col-12">Sample Body</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-7 col-12">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ff00ff; height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;">
      <div>
        <span>Scrollable</span>
      </div>
      <div style="height:4000px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```